# Android how to make the ripple effect with custom selector

Tags: android, textview, selector, ripple

I'm creating a custom view that represent a key pad, the layout is pretty simple it is just 9 textView placed in a table layout. I would like that when I press on one of the key there is that nice round ripple effect tat appears.

This is what I have done so far

drawable/button_selector.xml (color/selected is a light blue)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/selected" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="false"/>
</selector>
```

style.xml (I have put selectable_bg_borderless in attrs.xml)

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    [....]
    <item name="selectable_bg_borderless">@drawable/btn_selector</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Text.KeypadKey" parent="@style/AppTheme.Text">
        [..]
        <item name="android:background">?selectable_bg_borderless</item>
        [..]
</style>
```

layout/view_keypad.xml

```
<TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/key_1"
            style="@style/AppTheme.Text.KeypadKey"
            android:text="1"/>

        [....]
    </TableRow>
```

However when I press on the "1" I do have a blue background coming up but it is a raw and simple square.. How to I archieve something like this ?

[image]

Comment: try changing the background of your button to android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"

Comment: note that you have to use app combat theme for this

Comment: Uhh... yes that works

Comment: should i put that in answer and you mark it as solved so that it can help others ?

Comment: Yes go for it I have created a values-v21/style.xml and overidden with
 <item name="selectable_bg_borderless">?android:selectableItemBackgroundBorderless</item>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure the theme is appcompat and just change the background property of your view to

```
android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless
```